# add non-str foo to dict keys

Tags: python, dictionary

How to add [same] *non-str* foo to all *str* keys of a dictionary such that

```
a = {'continent': ['America', 'Africa'], 'country': ['USA', 'Egypt']}
```

becomes:

```
a = {foo(bar='continent', hello=world): ['America', 'Africa'], foo(bar='country', hello=world): ['USA', 'Egypt']}
```

Comment: What you man by *non-str foo* is `foo` a function?

Comment: foo looks like a named tuple...?

Answer (score 2):

Here I've used a dictionary comprehension to iterate over the keys and values in the dict `a` and apply whatever transformation the function `foo` defines:

```
def foo(bar, hello):
    return bar + hello  # or whatever you want to do

a = {'continent': ['America', 'Africa'], 'country': ['USA', 'Egypt']}
b = {foo(bar=k, hello='world'): v for k,v in a.items()}
```

print `b` yields:

```
{'continentworld': ['America', 'Africa'], 'countryworld': ['USA', 'Egypt']}
```

You don't have to use strings as dictionary keys in Python. The only requirement for dictionary keys is that they be hashable objects

From the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys):

> To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the hash function (e.g. through `__hash__`), equality comparison (e.g. through `__eq__` or `__cmp__`)

Comment: Functions can be used as keys in a dictionary, because all objects compare equal to only themselves unless `__eq__` or `__cmp__` is overridden.

Comment: @ppperry Great point - I just checked for `__eq__` and `__cmp__` on a function before adding that snippet, saw they weren't available and made the edit. Removing it now, thanks for teaching me something new.

Comment: Additionally, the `__cmp__` magic method was removed in python 3

Comment: @chucksmash - i am trying to get a non-str key